# Why does my TV screen stay dust-free while other screens do not?

Tags: electrostatics, electrons, charge, electronics, electrical-engineering

Recently I bought a pretty cheap flat-screen TV. Screen is IPS, semi-matte. 7 months now, I haven't cleaned it once, no dust at all. The TV works a few hours per day.
I was wondering why it does not collected dust, while my other computer & laptop screen which are also IPS, matte, collect dust like crazy.

Comment: Are you keeping your other screens vertical 24/7?

Comment: @KristofferSjöö Yes. I even tried to leave laptop screen less than 90 degrees, still gets dusty.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is unlikely that the electronics of the device is responsible for that. The times of high static voltage in TVs are long gone. The only electronic thing I think could be responsible for that is improper grounding. But I think even a manufacturer of cheap TVs cares about proper grounding, unless he wants to risk expensive lawsuits filed by the relatives of killed customers.

More likely the phenomenon is related to the plastics of casing or the screen. They could have treated it with antistatic agents (which I have read is not that uncommon), or the plastics itself could be minimally conductive, so that static charge does not accumulate on it. Plastics can be made conductive by immersing carbon dust in it (which is probably not advisable for a screen...).

One thing I have observed myself is that cleaning often makes things worse, because by that you introduce the charges to the surface, which stay there long enough to attract dust, thanks to the isolating properties of ordinary plastics. It's like rubbing a balloon or a vinyl record and attracting your hair with it. So, paradoxically, maybe simply the fact that you just bought the TV and have not cleaned it yet, might be responsible for it having stayed clean.

Comment: That's really cool. Though, I'd expect more the \$1000 laptops screen to have dust-repelling screen and less the \$130 TV  32' screen. They were bough at similar times, so technology was available for both.

Comment: Yeah, sometimes manufacturers fail to deliver even the most elementary features. Things happen, developers are only human. And after all it is always a question if the customer will pay for the feature (which is just one of hundreds or thousands).

Comment: I actually did not expect dust-free screens to exists. This is new for me. I'm surprised they're not advertising the hell out of this. Especially expensive computers like apple's or whatever.

Comment: `maybe simply the fact that you just bought the TV and have not cleaned it yet, might be responsible for it having stayed clean` I will try to clean only a little part of the screen 'cos it made me curious. If it will get dusty, I will add a new comment.

Comment: That would be fantastic. Experiments are the right way to learn about nature, and since I was only speculating, I'd be interested in your results too :-)

Comment: @jack Hey, I was just wondering, has the cleaned part of the screen gotten any dirtier during this last month?

Comment: @Krumuvecis No dust yet, not even the part I wiped. I will investigate more

Comment: @jack What about now?

Comment: @Krumuvecis It got a bit of dust, but much less than the back of the TV for example